# Setting Column Value Dynamically JDBC Appender : Log4j2

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I Have JDBC appender configured in log4j2 xml

```
<JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="TL_FX_LOG">
  <ConnectionFactory class="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.test.ConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
  <Column name="LOG_DATE" isEventTimestamp="true" />
   <Column name="LOG_DESC" pattern="%message" />
      <Column name="LOG_Batch" literal="someproperty" />
```

I need to set the value of literal(LOG_Batch) from Java Code.

```
Logger.debug("hello");
```

hello will be passed as %message value .But if i have a variable

```
String log_batch="test";
```

how to pass the log_batch variable value to JDBC appender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any pattern supported by PatternLayout can be used in a column pattern, so you could put that value in the ThreadContext map (`ThreadContext.put("log_batch", "test");`) in your code and insert it in the DB by configuring the appender with `<Column name="LOG_Batch" pattern="%X{log_batch}" />`.

Comment: I got a similar problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905449/memory-leak-with-log4j2-custom-hibernate-appender) but on a higher level. Is it possible to have a literal and a pattern mixed?

I need to have a ```select max + 1 ``` for my field POS 

```<Column name="POS" pattern="SELECT COALESCE(MAX(POS),-1)+1 FROM LAUFLOG WHERE SCHNITTSTELLE ='%X{schnittstelle}' AND VERSION = '%X{version}' AND LAUF = '%X{laufid}'"/>``` This gives me an error also when i change to literal